# How can i use a form inside html email and redirect to my local website with the request

Tags: laravel, forms, html-email, mailtrap

I'm trying to send a request from a form inside a email with html, I m using `mailtrap` to test those emails, here an example of what it looks like:

[image: example image]

I m not able to handle the request variable to get the description input, I also have an "id" and "accepted" params for the url, but these are injected in the blade template were is generated the body of email.

```
<form action="{{ route('vacations.response', ['id' => $vacationRequest->id, 'accepted' => 1]) }}" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="send this">
</form>
```

I tried to submit the form with `target="\_blank"` to my website but the function that handles the request from the email form I cannot be able to get description `textarea`.

```
Route::get('vacations/accept-request/{id}/{accepted}', [VacationRequestController::class, 'handleVacationResponse'])->name('vacations.response');
```

Basically I want to make a request from my html email and get that additional field.

Comment: You are not passing the value of your ```textarea``` when submitting the form